# Certifications required for a circuit board/ product

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, certification

I am developing a product that uses a bluetooth module (rigardo bmd-350 based off of the nrf52832) has a daughter/breakout board for interfacing with eeprom chips, pumps powered by small dc motors, and an external pre-made 12v power supply and am currently researching certifications needed and costs associated with them and frankly am unsure of what is needed.  The product would initially be sold in the USA/North America but eventually overseas.  What certifications and testing would be needed and what is the average cost and timeline for these? and would they only need to be tested on the bare circuit board or in the full finished enclosure?  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Certifications are almost universally *product level*; just what testing you will need to go through is highly product and target market dependent. The rules are highly complex (and vary by geographic area) which is why there are specialists in this area (the rules also change quite often). You really need to ask a specialist in this area.

Answer (score 0):

The type of certification will depend on the product you are selling, so getting in touch with a certified test agency to help guide you through the process is highly recommended.  Each country or region you sell into will have its own set of requirements (ie, hoops) to jump through to allow you to legally sell into that region.  For instance, even though the module you are using has an FCC ID for the module's approval, you may still have to test your product to ensure the product's unintentional radiation still falls within expected limits for US operation.  There are also potential safety requirements, EMC requirements, and labeling requirements.  This can be a daunting task to do on your own if you've never done it before, so finding a reputable expert or full service test agency is the way to go.